# What's the correct way of providing a default value for *print-length* in profiles.clj?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

For those that do not know what `*print-length*` stands for:

If you `(set! *print-length* 200)`, and you evaluate `(range)` in a REPL, which normally causes an infinite list of numbers to get printed, only the first 200 numbers will get printed.

I'm trying to set this as a default for all my REPLs in `profiles.clj`.
Right now I got this, but it doesn't work:

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-swank "1.4.4"]
                  [lein-catnip "0.5.0"]]
        :repl-options {*print-length* 200}} 
 :dev {:dependencies [[clj-ns-browser "1.2.0"]
                      [org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.5"]]}}
```

What's wrong with this?

**Update.** Tnx Michal for answering this. My fixed `profiles.clj` now looks like this. Note that it only works inside a project.

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-swank "1.4.4"]
                  [lein-catnip "0.5.0"]]
        :repl-options {:init (set! *print-length* 200)}} 
 :dev {:dependencies [[clj-ns-browser "1.2.0"]
                      [org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.5"]]}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:repl-options` needs to be a map of options supported by Leiningen's `repl` task; anything else will be ignored. `*print-length*` is not a valid option (and neither is `nil`; I'd have to check to be sure if the keys are evaluated here, but this won't work either way).

Instead you should use something like

```
:repl-options {:init (set! *print-length* 200)}
```

See `sample.project.clj` in the root of Leiningen's repository for a description of the available options (including `:init`).

Comment: Michal: I was trying this outside a repl (because I spin up a repl often just to try something) - got bitten by this again. Inside a project it works. Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

This is now also supported in project.clj:

```
:global-vars {*print-length* 20}
```