# How to set default value for *print-length* in deps.edn

Tags: clojure, deps-edn

My need is similar to [clojure - What's the correct way of providing a default value for *print-length* in profiles.clj? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664486/whats-the-correct-way-of-providing-a-default-value-for-print-length-in-profil).

I want to learn how to set default value for `*print-length*` inside `deps.edn` instead of `project.clj` of leiningen.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a :repl alias in your deps.edn:

```
{:aliases {:repl {:main-opts ["-e" "(set! *print-length* 2)" "-r"]}}}
```

And then you can start a repl with that:

```
clj -M:repl
user=> (range 20)
(0 1 ...)
```